# Scapy not showing all the fields in the packet

Tags: wireshark, scapy

I am writing a python script where I need to select specific fields from certain layers of packets. `packet.show()` produces:

```
###[ Padding ]###
load      = '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
None
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = 00:0e:8c:f5:12:af
  src       = 28:63:36:4b:c1:f0
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4L
     ihl       = 5L
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 167
     id        = 52667
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0L
     ttl       = 30
     proto     = tcp
     chksum    = 0x487c
     src       = 192.168.2.100
     dst       = 192.168.2.101
     \options   \
###[ TCP ]###
        sport     = 49898
        dport     = iso_tsap
        seq       = 4514968
        ack       = 11714804
        dataofs   = 5L
        reserved  = 0L
        flags     = PA
        window    = 8192
        chksum    = 0x8bdf
        urgptr    = 0
        options   = []
###[ TPKT ]###
           vrsn      = 3
           reserved  = 0
           length    = 127
###[ ISO8073 Data ]###
              li        = 2
              code      = 0xfL
              roa       = 0x0L
              tpdu_no   = 128
###[ S7CommPacketRequest ]###
                 unknown   = 0x32
                 type      = 1
                 reserved  = 0
                 seq_no    = 401
                 param_length= 110
                 data_length= 0
                 \param     \
                  |###[ Raw ]###
                  |  load      = '\x04\t\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00\x02\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00Q\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00P\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00S\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00U\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00R\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00T\x12\n\x10\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00\x01\x12\n\x10\x08\x00\x01\x00\x01\x84\x00\x00\x10'
```

The thing is that I need specific data from the Ethernet layer that are not grasped by Scapy (e.g. the opcode shown in Wireshark at the Ethernet layer)

[Wireshark capture of packet at Ethernet layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ylEF.png)

Does anyone know how to access such fields? (make them appear?)

Answer (score 0):

The `opcode` that you are referring to is not in the Ethernet layer, but is an ARP specific option.

For example, scapy can encode and decode ARP packets when they're received:

```
send( Ether(dst=clientMAC)/ARP(op="who-has", psrc=gateway, pdst=client),
  inter=RandNum(10,40), loop=1 )
```

Notice that that ARP layer sites above the Ether layer and has the `op` option that you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I realised that opcode is in ARP.

Something that is important here is that the haslayer function should only be used if the layer you want to "search" for is not encapsulated in all packets (such as ARP). An example of this is:

```
for packet in allPackets:
    if packet.haslayer("ARP"):
       opCode=int(indPacket["ARP"].op)
```